# XML file editing via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a JavaScript function that gets some text, and should insert that text as a node in an existing XML file (edit, not create a new one). It should add a new child node to existing nodes.

Is it possible to edit (and save to the file, located in the same directory as the index.html file) with Javascript/JQuery/AJAX?
I tried the following, but nothing is written to the file:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        var xmlDoc =  xhttp.responseXML;

        var newMassageElement = xmlDoc.createElement("new_element");
        var newTextElement = xmlDoc.createElement("text");
        var newText = xmlDoc.createTextNode("element_1");

        newTextElement.appendChild(newText);
        newMassageElement.appendChild(newTextElement);

        var x = xmlDoc.documentElement;
        x.appendChild(newMassageElement);

        xhttp.open("POST", "file.xml", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
        xhttp.send(xmlDoc);
    }
}
```

If not, is it possible to run a bash/python/perl script (that will edit the XML file) in Javascript/other? It should only pass two parameters (variables in my JavaScript function) to the script. It needs no feedback from the script.
I tried these, no luck:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "script.bash"
});

$.post("nana.pl");
```

*The website in not hosted on Apache/any other. It is a .html file on a Linux machine, being accessed through the network.*

Thanks!

Comment: You did not mention that if you are dealing with a web server or a serverside JavaScript. The answers can go yes / no based on the environment you are working. So better make a clarity to the question